# ngFor with dynamic function calls

Tags: angular, typescript

i have an array of objects called 'Action'. Every Action has 2 parameter: the function name and a boolean (which is not important now).

```
let  actionsArray: Action[] = [{name:"save",enabled:true},{name:"describe",enabled:true},{name:"delete",enabled:true}]
```

I use then ngFor to show a list of the functions. What i want to do is to bind the "click" event of every Action to its function dynamically.

```
<li *ngFor="let action of actionsArray">
        <button (click) ="this[action.name]()"> {{action.name}} </button>
</li>
```

I tried many ways without any success.

Comment: does anything prevent you from putting function references directly into your elements and doing e.g. `(click) = "action.fn()"`?

Comment: Why are you using the word `this` in the html?

Comment: @JanS thank you! , i tried that without success because i wasnt using the right syntax when writting the function. Now it is working.

Comment: @Patricio Vargas it was an example i found somewhere... i was just trying different syntax

Comment: okay, I'm gonna work on this right now. I will let you know if I figure it out

Comment: iirc `this` worked in AngularJS

Comment: @Patricio Vargas It is already solved, the way JanS proposes is good for me

Answer (score 1):

I created [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yxGXgB) with your code and it works. Also i added another `switch/case` approach.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <li *ngFor="let action of actionsArray">
        <button (click) ="[action.name]()"> {{action.name}} </button>
        <button (click) ="callAction(action.name)"> {{action.name}} </button>
    </li>
  `
})
class AppComponent {  
  actionsArray: {name: string, enabled: boolean}[] = [{name:"save",enabled:true},{name:"describe",enabled:true},{name:"delete",enabled:true}]

  callAction(actionName: string) {
    switch(actionName){
      case 'save' : return this.save();
      case 'describe' : return this.describe();
      case 'delete' : return this.delete();
    }
  }

  save() {
    alert('save');
  }

  describe() {
    alert('describe');
  }

  delete() {
    alert('delete');
  }
}
```